# Cannot connect to RDS from EC2 instance

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds, mysql-python

Tried the various threads still stuck.

1. I can successfully connect to RDS from both my local and google data studio, just not from this EC2. (all 3 have inbound rules in my rds security group, see #2)
2. Added an Inbound Rule to the RDS security group that is the private IP address of my EC2
3. Added Outbound Rule for port 3306  for my EC2 instance security group to 0.0.0.0/0
   (although not sure this is needed)

Trying to run the same python script I use in local to connect.
`engine_insert = sqlalchemy.create_engine('mysql+pymysql://root:password@rdsdb.abcdefg.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306/database')`

Comment: what does the error say?

Comment: @DanielFarrell sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'rdsdb.abcdef.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com' (timed out)")
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/14/e3q8)

Comment: Is the RDS publicly accessible, i.e. from outside of whatever VPC it's in? If so then you probably need to allow the EC2's public IP in the RDS security group.

Comment: connection timeout is a good fit for a munged security group rule: security groups drop (don't explicitly reject) traffic that doesnt match, so the sender eventually sees a timeout.  I agree with @404 that you likely are using a plublic address on RDS ( since you say you can reach from a different cloud) but not allowing the public address of EC2.

Comment: @404 & Daniel Farrell that fixed it!! But so, is this still the best secure way to do this? 
RDS is public but the SG is restricted to google data studio and my local ip for port 3306 (and now the ec2 public ip).  and then the ec2 instance is public, but the only inbound rule is ssh for my local ip

Comment: @stubbsy I wouldn't recommend this for production, but if this is only for testing purposes, that should be fine.

Comment: @jellycsc what would you recommend for production

Comment: @stubbsy keep the rds private

Comment: @jellycsc but wouldnt google data studio not be able to access it then?

Comment: Yes if you keep it private(& remove the public IP for RDS), you won't be able to connect it from outside.